# How to use mongodb in query in spring data @Query annotation

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

In my project I am trying to execute mongodb `in` using spring data `@Query` annotation as follows.

```
@Query("{'employerId' : ?0,  'state' : { $in: ?1 } ")
Page<T> findByEmployerIdAndStates(Pageable pageable, String employerId, final List<String> states);
```

With this i'm trying to execute query like below

```
{'employerId' : '367bdb30-e42b-4269-95e3-3c95e236c3da', 'state' : { $in: ['abc','test']}}
```

However I'm getting empty data set from spring repository even though query has data. Is above correct ? I could not found sample on this.

Comment: Try to execute the query in mongo shell and see if result is coming or not. Then move to spring.

Comment: Thank you @UdayChauhan. I have tried and result is coming.

Comment: there is typo 'state' can u correct and check

Comment: Have you got answer for this @vi

Answer (score 0):

try escaping the dollar sign in the query

```
@Query("{'employerId' : ?0,  'state' : { \$in: ?1 } ")
Page<T> findByEmployerIdAndStates(Pageable pageable, String employerId, final List<String> states);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct. You should enable trace logging as follows. Add the following in the application.properties file of your spring project.

`logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb=TRACE`

This would log the exact mongodb query which is executed at runtime. This should help you to figure out the root cause of your issue